# Need a query how to get this scenario

Tags: sql-server

I need this scenario based query.

```
SalesID Line    Noofitems   Category    Desc
SID12345    1   1           Metal-SI    Strong iron
SID12345    2   1           Plastic     Disposal
SID12345    3   1           Plastic     Disposal
```

Expected Output

```
SalesID     Totitems    Category            Desc
SID12345    3           Metal-SI,Plastic    Strong iron,Disposal
```

Comment: You’re not really providing enough information in your quesiton. If you’re asking what SQL statement would produce that output, then I’d suggest you explicitly say that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for xml path` approach here, with a `distinct` clause to remove duplicates while concatenating column values, followed by a `group by` on `SalesID`

Query will be like:

```
select 
    SalesID, 
    sum(Noofitems) as Totitems,
    STUFF(
            (
                Select 
                    DISTINCT ','+t1.Category 
                from tbl t1 
                    where t1.SalesID=t2.SalesID 
                for xml path('')
            ),1,1,'') 
            as Category,
    STUFF(
            (
                select 
                    DISTINCT ','+t1.[Desc] 
                from tbl t1 
                    where t1.SalesID=t2.SalesID 
                for xml path('')
            ),1,1,'') 
        as [Desc]
from tbl t2 
    group by SalesID
```

Link for demo sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d6bf5/8

Use `order by` in the inner query to change the order of concatenated strings.